# Ubuntu 14.04 Hot Corners not working after reboot

Tags: unity, unity-tweak-tool

I have installed the unity tweak tool for ubuntu 14.04 and I am using the hot corners feature. However, after I restart the computer, hot corners are not working and i have to turn them off and on again to fix this. Is there any solution to this problem?